# how to use CreateObject in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Sub InformationManagement(myTable As String)
    Dim myaccess As Object
    Dim mydata As String
    mydata = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Management.mdb"
    Set myaccess = CreateObject(mydata)
    With myaccess
        .Visible = True
        .DoCmd.OpenTable myTable
        .DoCmd.Maximize
    End With
    Set myaccess = Nothing
End Sub
```

There is a message error "Run-time error '429' ActiveX component can't create object" happened in Row -> Set myaccess = CreateObject(mydata)

Does anyone know how to resolve this? thank you very much

Comment: Your purpose seems to be to open a database connection. If so, you should use `ADODB.Connection` object

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ive not done this for a while but off the top of my head it should be more like..

```
Dim mydata As String
Dim myaccess As Object

mydata = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Management.mdb"
Set myaccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
With AccDatabase

    .OpenCurrentDatabase mydata 
    .DoCmd.OpenTable myTable
    .DoCmd.Maximize
End With
Set myaccess = Nothing
```